# \flusright in Tikz-timing

Tags: vertical-alignment, tikz-timing

MWE

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\usetikztiminglibrary{nicetabs}

\newcommand\gtikzset[1]{%
\begingroup%
\globaldefs=1\relax%
\pgfqkeys{/tikz}{#1}%
\endgroup}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikztimingtable}[
scale=2,
timing/rowdist=3ex,
]
\textnormal{}  &   @{\gtikzset{timing/rowdist=1}}\\
\textnormal{RS--232 Signal}  & @{\gtikzset{timing/rowdist=1}}\\
\textnormal{}  & @{\gtikzset{timing/rowdist=1}}\\
\textnormal{}  &  [y=4\yunit][line width=1pt] U L 2H 2L 5{2H} 2L 2L 2H 2{2L} L U \\
\extracode
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
%Left
\node[anchor=east] at (row1.north west){\scriptsize +15V};
\node[anchor=east] at (row3.west){\scriptsize --3V};
\node[anchor=east] at (row3.north west){\scriptsize 0V};
\node[anchor=east] at (row2.west){\scriptsize +3V};
\node[anchor=east] at (row4.south west){\scriptsize --15V};
%Right
\node[anchor=west] at (28,1){\scriptsize +15V};
\node[anchor=west] at (28,-0.5){\scriptsize +3V};
\node[anchor=west] at (28,-1){\scriptsize \phantom{+}0V};
\node[anchor=west] at (28,-1.5){\scriptsize --3V};
\node[anchor=west] at (28,-3){\scriptsize --15V};
%Horivontal
\shade[right color=red!60,left color=red!60](28,-0.5) rectangle(0,-1.5);
\shade[right color=green!60,left color=green!60](28,1) rectangle(0,-0.5);
\shade[right color=green!60,left color=green!60](28,-1.5) rectangle(0,-3);
%Vertical
\shade[right color=yellow!60,left color=yellow!60](2,-3) rectangle(1,1);
\shade[right color=yellow!60,left color=yellow!60](26,-3) rectangle(27,1);
\end{pgfonlayer}
\tablegrid
\end{tikztimingtable}
\end{document}
```

And output,
[image].

My problem is (like`-3V`) all in right voltages definitions flusright. How can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try choosing the same `anchor` as the left group, then add an x-shift to compensate for this. Note that the unit of length for the shift should be chosen relative to the font size (em, ex, ...) and not fixed units (pt, in, mm, cm, ...).

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\usetikztiminglibrary{nicetabs}

\newcommand\gtikzset[1]{%
\begingroup%
\globaldefs=1\relax%
\pgfqkeys{/tikz}{#1}%
\endgroup}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikztimingtable}[
scale=2,
timing/rowdist=3ex,
]
\textnormal{}  &   @{\gtikzset{timing/rowdist=1}}\\
\textnormal{RS--232 Signal}  & @{\gtikzset{timing/rowdist=1}}\\
\textnormal{}  & @{\gtikzset{timing/rowdist=1}}\\
\textnormal{}  &  [y=4\yunit][line width=1pt] U L 2H 2L 5{2H} 2L 2L 2H 2{2L} L U \\
\extracode
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
%Left
\node[anchor=east] at (row1.north west){\scriptsize +15V};
\node[anchor=east] at (row3.west){\scriptsize --3V};
\node[anchor=east] at (row3.north west){\scriptsize 0V};
\node[anchor=east] at (row2.west){\scriptsize +3V};
\node[anchor=east] at (row4.south west){\scriptsize --15V};
%Right
\node[anchor=east,xshift=6ex] at (28,1){\scriptsize +15V};
\node[anchor=east,xshift=6ex] at (28,-0.5){\scriptsize +3V};
\node[anchor=east,xshift=6ex] at (28,-1){\scriptsize \phantom{+}0V};
\node[anchor=east,xshift=6ex] at (28,-1.5){\scriptsize --3V};
\node[anchor=east,xshift=6ex] at (28,-3){\scriptsize --15V};
%Horivontal
\shade[right color=red!60,left color=red!60](28,-0.5) rectangle(0,-1.5);
\shade[right color=green!60,left color=green!60](28,1) rectangle(0,-0.5);
\shade[right color=green!60,left color=green!60](28,-1.5) rectangle(0,-3);
%Vertical
\shade[right color=yellow!60,left color=yellow!60](2,-3) rectangle(1,1);
\shade[right color=yellow!60,left color=yellow!60](26,-3) rectangle(27,1);
\end{pgfonlayer}
\tablegrid
\end{tikztimingtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option is to leave `anchor=west` as it is and specify a `text width` wide enough for all labels and aligned to the right as this:

```
\node[anchor=west,text width=5ex,align=right] at (28,1){\scriptsize +15V};
\node[anchor=west,text width=5ex,align=right] at (28,-0.5){\scriptsize +3V};
\node[anchor=west,text width=5ex,align=right] at (28,-1){\scriptsize \phantom{+}0V};
\node[anchor=west,text width=5ex,align=right] at (28,-1.5){\scriptsize --3V};
\node[anchor=west,text width=5ex,align=right] at (28,-3){\scriptsize --15V};
```

Comment: Perfect, it is working. @AboAmmar.